# Use csrf only for defined routes in restify

Tags: node.js, routes, csrf, restify

I have restify application (simple API).
We use csurf library for preventing CSRF requests.

But I need don't use CSRF validation on several routes.

First idea, which I think - this create array with routes for which I don't need use csrf and validate current route.

```
var routesNoCSRF = ['/api/route1', '/api/route2'];
if (routesNoCSRF.indexOf(currentRoute) === -1) {
  server.use(csrf({
    cookie: true,
    ignoreMethods: ['HEAD', 'OPTIONS']
  }));
}
```

But on this step I didn't have access to currentRoute

Second - this divide one API to 2 different APis - and for first use csrf validation for second - not. In this case - we create 2 different servers, which listen 2 different ports.

But i would to do this with using only one app. Is it possible ?

Comment: Did you already get this figured out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a complete example for ignoring routes on the csurf github page.

https://github.com/expressjs/csurf

Comment: Thank you for answer, we have a lot of routes and we require routes automatically (all files from folder). For this case - we can use 2 folders for routes - one (for which we don't need csrf) and second - for which we need csrf verifying. But now we decided another solution - use 2 folders with routes, 2 node servers and use ENV_VARIABLE for detecting should we use csrf or not (in app.js).